Next js is slower for on demand dynamic routes
my next js feels slower when we go to dynamic routes. and i can't prepare these routes at build time because routes will change after user logged in .
for example:
After succesfull login,user have list of items which is different according to user logged in so the routed can't be prepared at build time
i tried out to find any solution for this, but only got getStaticPaths or generateStaticPaths which doesn't work with this case

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
